# aria-describedby on containing div instead of input - usable?

Tags: wai-aria

Is it usable to put an aria-describedby on a div containing an input?

(Instead of just putting it on the input.)

```html
<p id="description">Description of input</p>

<div aria-describedby="description">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="text">
</div>
```

**Update:**

As Steve Faulkner said below, this can be done by putting a role="group" and an aria-labelledby attribute on the div. This achieves basically the same thing as fieldset-legend would. The advantage is: You can seperate the "legend" from the "fieldset". If that is not necessary, it is probably best to stick with the regular fieldset-legend.

In the link below this technique is explained:

[Using grouping roles to identify related form controls](http://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/wiki/Using_grouping_roles_to_identify_related_form_controls)

If you want to make use of both description and a label ( with role="application" ), see link below:

[Using the aria-describedby attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_aria-describedby_attribute)

Comment: Screenreaders can take advantage of these annotations

Comment: @Domysee - Yes I understood - but is it still usable when you put the aria attribute on a containing div instead of the input itself?

Comment: What is the reason for putting the attribute on the container instead of the element itself? A screenreader can read it anyway but why would you want it to *not* be on an input if I may ask?

Comment: @SidneyLiebrand - I was just wondering if it would also make sense to do it this way. Perhaps there can be multiple inputs in the container as well.

Comment: @J.T.Houtenbos I think in that case every seperate field would have it's own `aria-*` attribute which would make sense as a visually impaired user would like to know what to enter in every field :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not work as expected, for a few reasons:

1. a div element is generally not exposed in the accessibility tree so it presence (and it associated description string) will not be conveyed to the user
2. refer to [practical support for aria-describedby](http://w3c.github.io/aria-in-html/#aria-labelledby-and-aria-describedby)

Comment: Thans for your reply. I was just hoping the the div would somehow be exposed by the aria-describedby tag. So if I have multiple input elements wrapped in a div - I can not use 1 description? Or should I use the fieldset tag in this case instead of a div?

Comment: if the same description relates to multiple controls to expose the div add role="group" and aria-label="description", or if you want the visible text associated with the group use aria-labelledby="description" on the div instead.